# Is there a way to assign dynamic paint canvas to a vertex group

Tags: physics, vertex-groups, dynamic-paint

I want to assign dynamic paint canvas to just a vertex group instead of the whole object. is there a way to do so without having to separate the vertex group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Waves option of the Dynamic Paint modifier, but for the Paint option you can use basically the same method, just store and write to the vertex color instead of the position.

---

[image: comparisons]

[image: weight paint]

With Geometry Nodes, you can save the original position of each vertex before the Dynamic Paint modifier and then after it mix the current position with the original depending on a weight group.

[image]

If you don't need the waves to reflect at the border of the weight group, you can simply mix the original and deformed positions:

[image]

But if you want them to reflect, the regions must also be split before the Dynamic Paint and then, after it, merged together:

[image]

---

[image] $\text{Blender 3.6.5}$

Comment: Very good walkaround thanks