Dynamic paint waves only on one face
I want the dynamics paint waves on one side only, for example if I do the dynamic paint wave on a cube, there are waves on the 6 faces, I just want to have waves on the top face. Is it possible?


Does this answers your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304289/53447

I'm very sorry for the late answer, yes it answers my question. I will delete this question later. Thank you.

No need to delete, people who will find this topic on google will get redirected to the right place.

Ok, I'll leave my question here.
